# C fork() - What are the number of unique processes created by this code?

Tags: c, process, fork

In the following code segment, how many unique processes are created?

```
pid t pid;
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    fork();
}
fork();
```

It seems that the answer is 6, based upon the process tree that I drew. Is my reasoning right?

[image: process tree]

Comment: It seems wrong. At least 2 forks should be executed, but there is only one fork in the 1 - 4 path.

Comment: "answer i 6" seems correct assuming that all `fork()` are successful. It seems I failed to guess the meaning of the graph.  This is a graph I drew: https://i.imgur.com/Ald4J4n.png

Comment: I count only 5 process created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.  There are 5 processes created from this code for a total of 6 processes including the original.

To verify, adding the following two lines after the above code:

```
printf("pid: %d, parent: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
sleep(1);
```

Printed this on my machine (with comments added to match the pids with your tree:

```
pid: 2638, parent: 2498      // 1
pid: 2639, parent: 2638      // 2
pid: 2640, parent: 2638      // 4
pid: 2641, parent: 2639      // 3
pid: 2642, parent: 2639      // 5
pid: 2643, parent: 2641      // 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pid t pid;
pid = fork();
```

Process 1 executes the above line, creating process 2. Both process 1 and process 2 return from that `fork()`. Process 1 receives the PID of process 2. Process 2 receives 0.

```
if (pid == 0) {
    fork();
```

Only process 2 executes this line, creating process 3. Both process 2 and process 3 return from it.

```
}
fork();
```

Processes 1, 2, and 3 all execute the above line, creating processes 4, 5, and 6, respectively.

The graph in your question is correct, although I would have maybe ordered the children a bit differently along each row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct. If you want to be sure print the pid (using getpid())for each parent-son and count the unique numbers printed.